# Progress Error 54 - unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, openedge, progress-4gl

I have tried the solution by googling it. But im not able to find.

Error

> Error Code -54 : unable to get local issuer certificate: for 6ae7a2a5.0 in c:\Program Files(86)\OpenEdge_113\cert(9318).

As my understanding **6ae7a2a5.0** is uique id for certificate. But we are not able to find the name of the certificate to install in the server. How to find name of the certificate for 6ae7a2a5.0?

This issue happened after change the URL from http to https and its happening while showing pdf file in IE

Sample Code :

```
create server hWeb.
hWeb:connect(cWSDL) no-error.
if not hWeb:connected() then
do:
    pcMeddelande = error-status:get-message(1).
    hWeb:disconnect().
    delete object hPortType no-error.
    delete object hWeb no-error.
    return.
end.
```

Here in cwsdl variable we send "-wsdl  -WSDL https://example.com/OnLineService.asmx?wsdl "

We have imported all required certificates for the URL.

Comment: Perhaps you can shed more light on this by adding the url (if it's not internal or a secret), also please provide more information of what you really are doing. Do you use an Acrobat OCX, webview ocx or what is the setup?

Answer (score 2):

Surf to the address you want to access and download the certificate.

How you do this depends on your browser. In Chrome you open Developer Tools and go to the security tab where you press View Certificate:

[image]

Select the certificate and save to file (I have a Swedish Windows installation so it says Kopiera till fil...)

[image]

Follow the guide and save the certificate as a DER-encoded file.

[image]

Now your need to run `certutil` in the `proenv`-environment to import your certificate.

```
certutil -import <filename>
```

or

```
certutil -format DER-import <filename>
```

Possibly you might have to repeat this for the entire chain of certificates.

The chain can be found in the certificate dialogue you already opened - it has its own tab:

[image]

Official instructions found [here](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000043116?popup=true)

This is done more or less the same way in any browser.

Comment: We tried. A file  is created in  c:\Program Files(86)\OpenEdge_113\cert folder. But not in the unique name of 6ae7a2a5.0. Its saving in some other unique  name. Same error continues.

Comment: Did you repeat for each certificate in the chain?

Comment: Can you include more details. Code. Screenshots etc.

Comment: Same Code ,working fine for http . Showing error only for https. we are using symatric anti virus.

Comment: Just want to find certificate name for unique id 6ae7a2a5.0

Comment: We are not suppose to share URL or code as per company policy. But for http URL same code working. HTTPS its showing cerficate is missing with 6ae7a2a5.0 .

Comment: I understand. The problems is with the chain of certificates - at least one is missing...

Comment: Could u send personal id so that we can share the details.

Comment: [link](https://www.symantec.com/theme/roots) we tried importing all certificate to opengl certificate. But all are different from   6ae7a2a5.0

Comment: Might not be a Symantec Root certificate you are missing - all depends on the certificates of the URL you are trying to access in the first place.

Comment: Updating question with sample code and URL details. Kinldy check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164083/discussion-between-jensd-and-karthikeyan).

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and I managed to solve by just copying PEM content from certificate and save file with name of the hash.
This seems to be a bug of the Progress version, it can't match unique id with URL.